# Converting Lambert conformal conic to Lat/Lng

Tags: python, lambert-conformal-conic

I'd like to convert the following geographic representation to Lat / Lng (I guess this is called Lambert conformal conic, but it's the first time I've ever seen this).

- Projection: Lambert conformal conic
- False easting: 6200000.000000
- False northing: 3000000.000000
- Central meridian: -91.866667
- Standard parallel 1: 49.000000
- Standard parallel 2: 77.000000
- Latitude of origin: 63.390675
- Linear unit: metre (1.000000)
- Datum: North American 1983 (NAD83)
- Prime meridian: Greenwich
- Angular unit: degree
- Spheroid: GRS 1980

Source: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/92-160-g/92-160-g2021002-eng.htm

I am trying to find a Python library to perform the conversion, and I found this https://github.com/vraida/Lambert-projection, however, I'm not sure which parameters I'd need to plug in.

```
lamb = Lambert(
    (standard_parallel_1, standard_parallel_2),
    central_latitude, central_longitude,
    false_easting, false_northing,
    semimajor_axis, inverse_flattening
)
```

`standard_parallel_1`, `standard_parallel_2`, `false_easting` and `false_easting` are quite obvious, but I am not sure what the other 4 parameters should be.

Comment: Central lat/lon should be obvious, too. The other properties can be found by googling NAD83 and/or GRS1980. Note that the result is a NAD83 lat/lon, not a WGS84.

Comment: central lat I guess is Latitude of origin: 63.390675, central lon = Central meridian: -91.866667. Upon checking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum I found  semimajor_axis = 6356583.8 and inverse_flattening = 294.978698214. @Vince does this look correct?

Comment: No, that looks like NAD27/Clarke1866. You want the GRS80 line.

Comment: @Vince checking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_Reference_System_1980 I found semimajor axis = 6 378 137, and inverse flattening = 298.257222... Correct this time?

Comment: The page you initially referenced had those values, too.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for your help.